# Decreasing quantity elements in quantities array to get it to be in same ratio as array of ratios

Tags: algorithms, mathematical-programming

Problem Statement:

We want to update(only decrease allowed) elements of array to obtain a new array which is in same ratio as ratio array.
Example lets say you have quantity vector as [20, 50, 20] and ratio vector as [1, 2, 1]. Now you update quantity array to [20,40,20], so you have quantity elements in same ratio as ratio elements.

Note that we have elements of input vectors are natural numbers and we want output in natural number as well.

Comment: Can you credit the source where you encountered this?  What approaches have you considered? Where did you get stuck?  I suggest you research reapportionment/apportionment and see if you find anything useful.

Comment: You have not provided a full problem description. Do you want to decrease each element as little as possible? Or does any solution do?